# Reference request: Classical Mechanics as an Application to Smooth Manifolds

Tags: classical-mechanics, differential-geometry, resource-recommendations, hamiltonian-formalism, topology

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Classical Mechanics for Mathematician](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/23107/classical-mechanics-for-mathematician)

Last time I asked a question, but it does not sound specific. I am currently taking graduate topology class (using Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds), but I am in math program (not in physics), so I might lack physical intuition.
Is it better to learn Symplectic geometry first (such as da Silva's Lectures on Symplectic Geometry) then learn mechanics with symplectic geometry emphasis (such as Abraham & Marsden, etc), or is Spivak's Physics book self-contained in terms of both motivation and mechanics in manifold? How about Arnold? Is his physical explanation requires prerequisite in university level physics?

Comment: Just in case you are curious about other discussion (maybe my question is possibly a duplicate compared to these links, but the spirit of the question asked is more specific here) http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/23107/ , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9165/