# Prereqs for The Geometry of Physics by Frankel

Tags: mathematical-physics, soft-question, resource-recommendations, differential-geometry, topology

I'm interested in giving The Geometry of Physics a read, and I was wondering what the mathematical and (more importantly) physical prerequisites are.  My background is a bit stronger on the mathematical side, and I'm worried that if heavy (or even moderate) exposure to physics is required that I'll miss out on a lot.  If someone has read it and has a good sense of this sort of thing, I'd very much appreciate the input!

A link to the [book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1107602602).

Comment: I've read a part of this book, lot of inconsistency and notation abuse is there in it.

Comment: Please use additional tags to describe this post.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/6047/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2528/2451  and links therein.

Comment: Hi AsinglePANCAKE, prerequisites questions fit poorly on this Q&A site for various reasons, e.g. the answer tend to be _primarily opinion-based,_ I close this question _as a duplicate,_ not because it necessarily is an exact duplicate, but to point you in the right direction.

Comment: @Qmechanic thanks!  I had seen those answers, it's just that my math background, while stronger than my physics, often proves inadequate for recommended books in the "physics for mathematicians" category.  I suppose this is the burden of the academic purgatory I face!  Might you suggest a medium more appropriate for the nature of the question?  Opinions are actually all I really wanted.

Comment: @Qmechanic same question.